# Slow codes from functions in Python Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, performance

I am trying to run a specific function (stats.boxcox) in a faster way in Python, but both codes I am using run very slow. Is there a way to do this in a more efficient way in Python?

First code:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from scipy import stats

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(1,100,size=(100, 4)), columns=list('ABCD'))

df_new = pd.DataFrame()
for column in list(df):
        df_new[column], lam = stats.boxcox(df[column])
```

Second code:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from scipy import stats

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(1,100,size=(100, 4)), columns=list('ABCD'))

df2_a = df.apply(lambda x: stats.boxcox(x))
df2_al = list(zip(*df2_a))
df2 = pd.DataFrame(df2_al[0]).T
```

Comment: Could it be that not specifying `lambda` leads to longer runtimes? In the [source code](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/4fab4fd/scipy/stats/morestats.py#L946-L1057) it terminates early if `lambda` is given. Maybe try `df_new[column] = stats.boxcox(df[column], lmbda=1)` in your first example and see if the performance improves.

Comment: I need the stats.boxcox to find the lamda tha maximizes the log-likelihood function

Answer (score 0):

We can do it in a parallel way using [`ProcessPoolExecutor`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor) like this:

```
from concurrent.futures import ProcessPoolExecutor

# utils function
def cpu_tasks(func, *args):

    # set chunksize to be even 
    with ProcessPoolExecutor(max_workers=None) as tp:
        result = tp.map(func, chunksize=10, *args)
    return list(result)

def get_box(s):
    return stats.boxcox(s)[0]

# make column list
obj_lst = [df[x].tolist() for x in df.columns]

ddf = pd.DataFrame(cpu_tasks(get_box, obj_lst)).T
ddf.columns = list('ABCD')

print(ddf.head())

           A          B          C          D
0   8.906146  23.867250  23.682790  16.669473
1  16.948358  11.752727  18.120534  15.678950
2  23.892165   7.159087   1.693517  17.055528
3  11.210063   5.720299  29.496806  13.348581
4   6.588403  29.940734  35.874053   4.101704
```

Comment: I get the following error message: BrokenProcessPool: A process in the process pool was terminated abruptly while the future was running or pending.

Comment: What do you mean when saying where?

Comment: are you running it in a jupyter notebook or ipython kernel?

Comment: Jupyter notebook

Comment: well, try to restart your nb kernel and run this code, probably good to set `max_workers = 4` initially, run the code on a sample of data and later you can increase it.